# how to wrire grok expression for json

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Hello can any one help me in writing a grok patter for this json.

```
{  
   "loggerFqcn":"org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog",
   "level":"INFO",
   "endOfBatch":true,
   "thread":"[cridtest].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01",
   "message":"[[Application = CorrelationID PoC]  [serverTime=2017-10-20T11:43:06.932-04:00] [CorrelationID = 5dec5af0-b5ad-11e7-b80d-f8597191971c] ]",
   "threadPriority":5,
   "threadId":88,
   "@timestamp":"2017-10-20T15:43:07.143Z",
   "port":60797,
   "@version":"1",
   "host":"73.132.64.252",
   "loggerName":"org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor",
   "timeMillis":1508514186945
}
```

Comment: You're better served with the json filter/codec, as sysadmin1138 proposed. It will be much easier and less brittle.

Answer (score 4):

If that JSON is in fact well formed, you will be far better served using the `json {}` filter to parse that. Assuming that's coming in on the `message` field:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "json_data"
  }
}
```

This will dump the parsed datastructure as sub-fields under the `json_data` field. You can use later `mutate {}` filter calls to drop the fields you don't want, or locate them into a different part of the event.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field    => { "host" => "%{json_data.host}" }
    remove_field => [ "json_data.host" ]
  }
}
```

Which will move the encoded `host` to the top of the event.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this pattern generator :

```
https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/
```

Example `Grok-pattern`:

```
{%{QS}:%{QS}, %{QS}:%{QS}, %{QS}:true, %{QS}:%{QS}, %{QS}:%{QS}, %{QS}:5, %{QS}:88, %{QS}:%{QS}, %{QS}:60797, %{QS}:%{QS}, %{QS}:%{QS}, %{QS}:%{QS}, %{QS}:1508514186945}
```